# Count the MongoDB collection by iterating over it doesn't yield the correct count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

With the following code, I would iterate over the MongoDB collection to compute its count.(with loop, limit and sort by _id ascendingly)

Ignore the fact there are other ways to compute the count since I am using this way to do other things(This code just illustrates the fact that I can't fetch out all the documents).

But it doesn't yield the correct the count. 
The total documents of my collection should be 12637833,
but with the following code, the count printed is 12602135.

That is, there are about 30 thousand gap between them.

Can someone help what may leads to this problem? Thanks!

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject sorter = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);
    ObjectId largestObjectId = null;
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {  
        DBCursor cursor = c.find(query).sort(sorter).limit(200000);
        if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            count++;
            BasicDBObject document = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
            if (document == null) {
                continue;
            }
            largestObjectId = (ObjectId) document.get("_id");
        }

        query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("$gt", largestObjectId));


        cursor.close();
    }

   System.out.println("Total Count is: " + count)
```

Comment: Is it a sharded collection?

Comment: Thanks @hyades for the reply. Yes.

Comment: maybe it is related to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5931. Instead of your `find` query, can you try the aggregation query `[{$match: query}, {$sort: {sorter}}, {$limit: 200000}]`

Comment: Thanks @hyades. let me try,Thanks!

Comment: @hyades. Aggregation only supports 16M RAM, which is not applicable to my case. in my case, each document is above 32K, that is the limit should only be below 500(not include some really large document) Is there way to work around this size limit?Thanks!

Comment: Add the option to aggregation `{allowDiskUse: true}`

Comment: @hyades using Aggregate/match/sort/limit yield the same result, that is,there are still 30000 in gap.

Answer (score 0):

The mismatch in count of the documents can happen only in an environment where one thread reads the data and other thread writes something into the database(i.e. In a multi threaded application in which one thread writes to mongodb and another performs certain operation).

Moreover when we have DBCursor for iterating collection with 12637833 records, not all the records will be loaded initially into the memory(JVM memory) instead it would be lazily fetched from the database.

Interestingly in a multithreaded application you can find difference between DBCursor length and iterating the cursor and obtaining the count, since when we use length or toArray on a DBCursor will irrevocably turn DBCursor into an array. So extra precaution should be taken before invoking toArray or length in DBCursor since it will suddenly increase the records in the memory. Say if we have ten million records, then there will be a ten-million element array in memory. So always use skip() and limit() to minimize the results before using length or toArray in a DBCursor.